# Computing Jacobian in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement a Jacobian matrix for the function:

> f = [[x + siny], [y + sinx]]

where, f1 = x + siny and f2 = y + sinx. Now, the general Jacobian for this vector-valued function is:

> J = [[1, cos(1)], [cosx, 1]]

And the Jacobian matrix at the point (-2, 1) equals:

> J(-2, 1) = [[1, 0.54], [-0.42, 1]]

How can I implement this using TensorFlow 2.0 GradientTape?

The code for a **different toy** example using TF2.0 Jacobian has the code:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  x  = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0])
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x
jacobian = g.jacobian(y, x)
# jacobian value is [[2., 0.], [0., 4.]]
```

I tried the following code:

Comment: Not very clear what your question is. Seems you already know how to compute jacobian. What's the issue here?

Comment: @thushv89 I want to create the Jacobian for given math equations and NOT the toy Jacobian TF code.