# Jacobian of a vector in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, automatic-differentiation

I think this question has never been properly answered 8see [How to calculate the Jacobian of a vector function with tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346290/how-to-calculate-the-jacobian-of-a-vector-function-with-tensorflow) or [Computing Jacobian in TensorFlow 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779368/computing-jacobian-in-tensorflow-2-0)), so I will try again:

I want to compute the jacobian of the vector valued function `z = [x**2 + 2*y, y**2]`, that is, I want to obtain the matrix of the partial derivatives

```
[[2x, 0],
 [2, 2y]]
```

(being automatic differentiation, this matrix will be for an specific point).

```
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    x  = tf.Variable(1.0)
    y = tf.Variable(4.0)
    z = tf.convert_to_tensor([x**2 + 2*y, y**2])

    jacobian = g.jacobian(z, [x, y])
    print(jacobian)
```

Obtaining

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([2., 0.], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([2., 8.], dtype=float32)>]
```

I want to obtain naturally the tensor

```
[[2., 0.],
 [2., 8.]]
```

not that intermediate result. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    x  = tf.Variable(1.0)
    y = tf.Variable(4.0)
    z = tf.convert_to_tensor([x**2 + 2*y, y**2])

    jacobian = g.jacobian(z, [x, y])
    print(np.array([jacob.numpy() for jacob in jacobian]))
```

Result

```
[[2. 0.]
 [2. 8.]]
```